# Convert a string of escaped hex to a hex number in Python

Tags: python, string, hex

How do I convert a string of escaped hex characters to a single hex number?

Reading from a socket I get a string of \xFF\xFF\xFF.., etc. I want to convert this to a hex number, 0xFFFFFF, keeping any insignificant 0s, so \x00\xFF should be 0x00FF. I have tried various functions from binascii, but I have not had any luck.

Comment: your_string.decode('utf-16')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack):

```
>>> struct.unpack('>I', '\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF')  # >, !: big (network) endian
(4294967295,)
>>> hex(struct.unpack('>I', '\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF')[0])
'0xffffffff'

>>> struct.unpack('>H', '\x00\xff')
(255,)
>>> '0x{:04x}'.format(struct.unpack('>H', '\x00\xff')[0])
'0x00ff'
>>> '0x{:04X}'.format(struct.unpack('>H', '\x00\xff')[0])
'0x00FF'
```

[Format characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) used:

- `I`: 4-bytes unsigned int
- `H`: 2-bytes unsinged int

---

**UPDATE**

If you indent to convert arbitrary binary string into hex string, you can use [`binascii.hexlify`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify):

```
>>> import binascii
>>> '0x' + binascii.hexlify('\xFF\xFF\xFF')
'0xffffff'
>>> '0x' + binascii.hexlify('\x00\x00\xFF')
'0x0000ff'
```

Comment: Sorry should have specified that in some cases there is not a good string format in struct. In some cases it may by 1 octets or 8 octet or 128 octets

Comment: @dvp, No problem. I updated the answer to include another solution that you may want. Thank you for your fast feedback.

Comment: @dvp please take an effort and read docs. It returns you a sequence of converted values and you can specify byte-lenght of single value using different formats. You understand, that you need to specify how you interpret the stream, do you? Computer cannot read your mind.

Comment: binascii.hexlify requires a byte not a string. I just copy pasted your code and ran. Using Python 3.7

Comment: @jasoos, `'0x' + binascii.hexlify(b'\x00\x00\xFF').decode()` for Python 3.x.